# Clone anchor tag link with text in div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

```js
$( ".post-title > a" ).clone().prependTo( ".post-text" ).text("View More");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.msn.com/">MSN</a> 
</div> 
</div>
```

I want to show new text 'View More' with same link in the div. Now it is showing all links in same div with 'View More' text.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you want to achieve. Could you please clarify? Do you want to show link only from first div?

Comment: You need to write an explicit loop for this, so that you can select the _proper_ `.post-text` element, that is the ancestor of the link you cloned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are prepending your cloned element to each `.post-text` element. So every `.post-text` will have all cloned elements.

Create a function that runs through each `.post-title` element.

```js
$('.post-title').each(function () {
$(this).find('> a').clone().prependTo($(this).closest('.post-text')).text('View more');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.msn.com/">MSN</a> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted answer same thought you were earlier than me. @SKeurentjes

Answer (score 0):

You have to just loop through using class `post-text` and pick nested child element using `.find()` function and apply logic.

```js
//$( ".post-title > a" ).clone().prependTo( ".post-text" ).text("View More");



$('.post-text').each(function(i, obj) {
var postTitleElem = $(this).find(".post-title > a");
 console.log(postTitleElem);
  $(postTitleElem).clone().prependTo(this).text("View More");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="post-text" > 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.google.com/" >Google</a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="post-text"> 
<div class="post-title"> 
<a href="https://www.msn.com/">MSN</a> 
</div> 
</div>
```